# numpy.insert with the target array position being -1 isnt the last position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to insert a value to the last position of a numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0]])
np.insert(a, -1, 2, 1)
>>>> array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 0]])
```

np.insert(the_list, the_position, the_value, the_axe)

normally, -1 is the last position of an array, but as you can see, the newly created array as the 2 in second last position. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html). The index is the index ***before which*** its inserted.  You want `np.append`

Comment: you are right, I didnt see this, how can I insert it in the last position then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) `numpy.insert` inserts the given elements *before* the given index:

> **obj** : *int, slice or sequence of ints*
>
> Object that defines the index or indices **before** which *values* is inserted. (Emphasis mine)

If you want to just add an element to the end of the array then you're looking for [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) which works the same way but without the index parameter and adds to the end of the list.

> `numpy.`**`append`(** *arr, values, axis=None* **)**
>
> Append values to the end of an array.

---

If you think about it, this make sense as if you have the array:

```
[3, 7]
```

And you tried to insert the value 4 and index 0, then it would do:

```
[4, 3, 7]
```

And using that logic you should always add the element before, otherwise how would you place an item at the beginning of a list? You'd need a `prepend` function.

If you're going to need either a `prepend` function or `append` function to allow inserting at ends of an array, I think it makes the most sense to implement the `append` function as it's more frequently needed.

Comment: for some reason I cant append to my (1,4) dimension array if I state that I want to append to the axe 1. I found a way around by stating no axe, which will flatten the array and then reshaping it into a (1,5) array. I need it to have 2 axes for dot multiplication

Comment: @tissuebox are the *axes* (plural of *axis* not *axe*) indexed from 0 or 1, try using 2 as your axis argument. I don't use numpy so i can't provide a definitive answer to that but that's my best guess